# NodeJS, DOM environment, HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend, web-development-server

I was wondering if there is a way to implement NodeJS Back-End to a Front-End DOM environment. I have an application written in NodeJS but I want the users to be able to connect to a regular html page with a responsive GUI on my hosting solution, for that I am going to need to access my functions from NodeJS files and reference it as a script for the Front-End html. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: More details would help

Comment: it really sounds like Babel can do just what you need, but it's depending on what you mean, @user13043325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways:

## 1. Move backend code to frontend

If your javascript code can be run in a browser there's actually no reason to use node.js at all.

## 2. API

The standard way to do this is to have a node.js backend which works as a webserver (ie: [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/)), providing a REST API that interfaces with the node.js functions you want to be able to access on frontend. To interact with the api on the frontend you can use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`. A bonus to this method is if it's applicable you can run the backend on a remote host with minor changes

## 3. WebSocket

If you have data that has to be near real-time and/or changes frequently a websocket might be the best route. You can install a package like [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) on the backend and use the builtin [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) on frontend.

Comment: depending on how the backend would be used, WebSocket can be used if there should be some live updates pushed from the server, but the rest of your answer I agree

Comment: When using express, I can only display my page on localhost. These are new waters for me and I will do some more reading but I am confused as to how express can help me show the page I want on my hosting solution.

Comment: @user13043325 did you try using `cors`? https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Comment: Express "connects" the front end with your back end code. When you send a request from the front end (your HTML page) using JS (for example `fetch`), Express can catch the request, interpret it, run your back end code (you already have that), then serve the response back to your page.

Comment: hmmm, I will do some reading on that library and keep you posted. Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: @ridderhoff, you forgot to change the first line "There are two ways:"

Comment: @montrealist Thank you for your response, how would the fetch argument look like on the front end to retrieve backend

Comment: `fetch('/path/to/api?query=here', {options: here}, callbackMethod)`

Comment: The topology I used that utilizes the fetch method mentioned by riderhoff and montrealist, worked. Thank you for aiding me on my project!